# How to use CAS or pthread in inter process synchronization of shared memory?

Tags: c++, pthreads, ipc, shared-memory

I want to use this stuct to control shared memory inter process synchronization.

```
struct shmLock {
        std::atomic_uint32_t user_count;
        pthread_mutex_t      mutex;
    };
```

If someone use `shmLock`, when the `user_count == 0`, I will initialize `mutex` then I use CAS to increase `user_count`.
If someone release `shmLock`, I use CAS to decrease `user_count`.When the `user_count` decreases to 0, I will destroy `mutex`.

```
class myLock {
public:
    myLock(shmLock* lock) : m_lock(lock) {
        uint32_t user_count = m_lock->user_count.load();
        if (user_count == 0) {
            pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr{};
            pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
            pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
            pthread_mutex_init(&m_lock->mutex, &mutex_attr);
        }
        m_lock->user_count.compare_exchange_strong(user_count, user_count + 1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_lock->mutex);
    }
    ~myLock() {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_lock->mutex);
        uint32_t user_count = m_lock->user_count.load();
        m_lock->user_count.compare_exchange_strong(user_count, user_count - 1);
        if (user_count == 0) {
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_lock->mutex);
        }
    }
private:
    shmLock* m_lock;
};
```

I have three questions.

1. Can I not use `user_count` to control the init and destroy of `mutex`, and directly init in constructor and destroy in destructor each time.
2. If `compare_exchange_strong` failed, what I should do.
3. I don't think this method is good. Is there any other better way to control the inter process synchronization of shared memory

Comment: Why use pthread_mutex? Can't you use std::mutex and std::shared_lock?

Comment: Also, C or C++, pick one.

Comment: I prefer to C++, but std::mutex can be used to shared memory?

Comment: In addition to the other problems noted, where is `mutex_attr` defined?  If it's in a shared scope such as file scope or an object member your use of `mutex_attr` is likely not thread safe.  And you also need to call `pthread_mutexattr_destroy()` when you are done.

Comment: sorry, I forget it. I will correct it in my code

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are multiple synchronization problems in your code. For example, in your constructor of `myLock` you are fetching the user count and checking it in an if statement. What if another process is scheduled and increases or decreases that value after your check? Moreover, you need to think about acquire-release memory order when you are talking about mutual exclusion. If you need to take action based on user count then take a look at std::shared_ptr's use count usage internally. More specifically, take a look at the source code of its constructor and destructor.

Most of the primitive thread synchronization constructs are not compatible with IPC but you can refer to [atomics for IPC](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/atomics.lockfree#4) for more information about IPC atomics.

Maybe the following may help you:

```
struct ShmLock
{
    ShmLock()
    {
        pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr{};
        pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
        pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED);
        pthread_mutex_init(&m_mutex, &mutex_attr);
    }

    ShmLock(const ShmLock&) = delete;
    ShmLock(ShmLock&&) = delete;
    ShmLock& operator=(const ShmLock&) = delete;
    ShmLock&& operator=(ShmLock&) = delete;

    ~ShmLock()
    {
        pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_mutex);
    }

    inline void lock() const
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mutex);
    }

    inline void unlock() const
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_mutex);
    }

    private:
    mutable pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;
};

class MyLock
{
    public:
    explicit MyLock(ShmLock& lock) : m_lock(lock)
    {
        m_lock.lock();
    }
    
    ~MyLock()
    {
        m_lock.unlock();
    }

    private:
    ShmLock& m_lock;
};
```

Comment: If not based on count, how to ensure that when a process initializes pthread, other processes will not initialize the pthread

Comment: Why don't you initialize your objects at init time?

Comment: My idea is that if one process initializes pthread, then other processes don't need to initialize it. Since I don't know which process will start first, I chose to control it based on count.

Comment: *Most of the primitive thread synchronization constructs are not compatible with IPC* Huh???  POSIX `pthread_mutex_t`, `pthread_cond_t`, `pthread_rwlock_t`, and `sem_t` all support being shared between processes.  AFAIK the only POSIX synchronization primitive that *doesn't* is `pthread_spinlock_t`

Comment: I have shared a new code snippet. Does it help?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I meant standard library primitive constructs, not the POSIX ones.

Comment: @siadynamic YES, It's helpful. Thanks a lot